# Global variable scope in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

This might sound very basic, but I have just started to play around with meteor.
I see how it's possible to seamlessly have access to database like entities (Collections) both on the server and the client, and sync it automatically.

However I don't see yet how I can snyc a simple variable accross the server and all clients. Something like a global variable. I don't need a fancy mongo collection, just a simple variable. :)

Comment: What do you intend to do with that variable?

Comment: I would like to have simple global application state variables, like number of users logged in, or some global config variable that applies to all connected user sessions. I realize that MongoDB collections could be used for this, but I feel that it's a bit overkill for some simple variables. Isn't it? :)

Comment: I think it depends how complex your application is, one variable synced in a Collection seems overkill but as you application grows you could store all sorts in a generic "config" collection or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Meteor.methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) to get and set variables in the server. But I don't think there is a way to push changes to other clients like changes of collections do.

So you have to take care that everything stays in sync. You should really use a collection for this or get the information from an existing collection.

e.g. a connected user could set a flag in its collection item and the reactivity magic would do the rest ;)

```
Users.find({connected:true}).count();
```